# Using PHP & AJAX to submit a form, getting "undefined variable" when placing validation variable in markup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

When my page loads, it displays:

> #### Notice: Undefined variable: titleErr in index.php on line 141

I defined `$titleErr` at the beginning of my PHP, what else am I missing?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $titleErr = ''; 
    $title = '';

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    if(isset($_GET)) {

        if (empty($_GET['page_title'])) {
            $titleErr = 'Name is required';
        } else {
            $title = test_input($_GET['page_title']);
        }

    }
?>
```

```js
$(function() {
 $('form').submit(function(e) {
  $page_title =  $('input[name="page_title"]').val();
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'save_to_wp.php',
   datatype: 'json',
   data: {
    page_title: ($page_title)
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id = "save-dam" class = "tiny reveal" data-reveal>
        <form action = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' class = "row">
            <div class = "small-12">
                <label>Save as</label>
            </div>

            <div class = "small-12">
                <input type = "text" placeholder = "Page Name" name="page_title" />
                <span class="error"><?php echo $titleErr;?></span>
            </div>

            <div class = "small-12">
                <button type = "submit" class = "button pill">Save</button>
            </div>

            <div class = "small-12">
                <button id="form-cancel" class = "button pill cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this all of your code for index.php?

Comment: @Joseph_J No, it's a big-ish page - would be huge to post. The page has existed and been working until I added the form. The form even works except for this error msg. The form is in a Foundation pop-up, and that is where the error is displayed.

Comment: Well we need to see more code.  Especially around line 141 on the index.php file.

Comment: I edited the snippet to include the whole div containing the pop-up form. "Line 141" is the line with the undefined variable. There's not any more PHP in the markup associated with the form. My edit just inserted a bunch more HTML.

Comment: what line is 141?

Comment: The line with the undefined variable:
<span class="error"><?php echo $titleErr;?></span>

Answer (score 0):

Another member posted an answer and suggested that scope was an issue but deleted it.  He may have been right despite the fact that no where in the code you have provided us does $titleErr get called out of scope.  Maybe somewhere else on your page idk.  You could trouble shoot that by declaring `global $titleErr;` at the top of you page.

I did see some errors in the code that you posted unrelated to $titleErr.

Your javascript should look like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'save_to_wp.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                page_title: $('input[name="page_title"]').val()
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The way that you were interchanging js variables with php variables does not work.

Secondly the javascript needs to be loaded after your form.